# Allow add new record through combobox dropdown list

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have Combobox the data source coming from a customer table

```
combo_customers.DataSource = AddingDebit_con.Get_All_Customers();
combo_customers.DisplayMember = "customer_fullname";
combo_customers.ValueMember = "customer_id";
```

`AddingDebit_con` is .cs file contain the below code

```
public DataTable Get_All_Customers()
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DAL.SelectData("All_customers", null);
    return dt;
}
```

`DAL` is the folder which contain `DataAccessLayer.cs` for sql-connection

`All_customers` is a SQL-server procedure as below

`ALTER proc [dbo].[All_customers]  AS select customer_fullname,customer_id from Customers`

every thing above is working as I want ,but the Client asking me if he could add new customer directly from the Combobox in case the customer not listed in the table source (Combobox drop down list)

The issue icant figure that the Combobox displays the members **(Customer_name)** but insert the value **(customer_id)**!

Comment: You should be setting the `DataSource` after the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. It's not the end of the world doing it like you are but it's better the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I used an if condition with the reload form:

```
if (combo_customers.SelectedValue == null )
{
    // first get the value of new customer's ID which = last ID+1
    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(CustomersMangment.dgv_search.Rows[CustomersMangment.dgv_search.Rows.Count - 2].Cells[0].Value);
    int total = amount + 1;
     
    addingCustomers.tb_phone.Text = "";
    addingCustomers.comb_addess.Text = "text";
    addingCustomers.tb_CustomerName.Text = combo_customers.Text;
    addingCustomers.dtp_addingDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
    AddingDebit_con.InsertCustomer(addingCustomers.tb_CustomerName.Text, addingCustomers.tb_phone.Text, addingCustomers.comb_addess.Text, addingCustomers.dtp_addingDate.Value);
    //2nd reload the form to reload combobox items
    AddinDebits_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    combo_customers.SelectedValue = total;

    // Adding cmd
    AddingDebit_con.AddingNewDebit(int.Parse(combo_customers.SelectedValue.ToString()), dtp_addingDebit.Value, Convert.ToInt32(tb_amount.Text));
    MessageBox.Show("done");
    tb_amount.Text = "";
    tb_date.Text = "";
    dtp_addingDebit.Value = DateTime.Now;

    //Refresh 
    this.dgv_withdraw.DataSource = AddingDebit_con.DataGrid_Withdraw();
    lbl_total.Text = combo_withdrawTotal.Text;
 }

 else { 
     AddingDebit_con.AddingNewDebit(int.Parse(combo_customers.SelectedValue.ToString()), dtp_addingDebit.Value, Convert.ToInt32(tb_amount.Text));

     MessageBox.Show("done");
     tb_amount.Text = "";
     tb_date.Text = "";
     dtp_addingDebit.Value = DateTime.Now;

     //Refresh 
     this.dgv_withdraw.DataSource = AddingDebit_con.DataGrid_Withdraw();
      lbl_total.Text = combo_withdrawTotal.Text;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**